# Enterprise app install error

Tags: ios, iphone, enterprise

App has strange behavior. On most devices app installs well. But some devices do not send third request for getting app.
Here phone terminal output:

```
Transmitting packaged session fragments in file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/80D4D4A0-92BA-4245-92BC-18694C375CD9/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/.../analytics/v1/PACKAGED/1446810311335_87dd56a79fc54e1b83e7685398f565f0/1446810336841_462B9BF5-B36B-4107-A61F-13D889382C72/
Nov  6 15:45:49 iPhone App[2933] <Warning>: [Crashlytics:Answers] Successfully transmitted packaged session fragments
Nov  6 15:45:51 iPhone nsurlsessiond[109] <Error>: Task 18 for client <CFString 0x19cb0af00 [0x1a0f19b68]>{contents = "com.apple.itunesstored"} completed with error - code: -999
Nov  6 15:45:51 iPhone itunesstored[115] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x1492f1910> ... (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/502C7C92-0960-4117-B255-4A47DD38798C/741673972726020873.app> withPhase:0
Nov  6 15:45:51 iPhone itunesstored[115] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: ....Loading - <NSProgress: 0x1492e8f10> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 1 of 1   called, removing progress from cache
Nov  6 15:45:51 iPhone lsd[81] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: 0x14658cb30> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   to 0
```